# Snowflake Sql Query to find the time taken between specific task flow for completing the coding task for an encounter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]Hope you are doing well!.. An encounter is a combination of ctextid and vbillid.. There are multiple events that place before an encounter is coding completed.. Sometimes the tasks don't get coding completed at all... Following represents the tasks flow (eventtype) for which the difference in the event time should be calculated in minutes...Please find below the input and the output tables...can you please help me here.. Distinctnumberofcoders is calculated as distinct count of user_id)..

170109-image.png

Input table

```
create table ##input
(event_time datetime2,
event_type varchar(1000),
user_id varchar(100),
ctextid int,
vbillid int)

insert into ##input values
('1/11/2022 1:21:02 PM','Start Work Clicked','am21','10021','21'),
('1/11/2022 1:46:02 PM','Coding Complete Clicked','am21','10021','21'),
('1/12/2022 1:46:02 PM','Start Work Clicked','am31','78321','561'),
('1/12/2022 1:51:02 PM','Home Button Clicked','am31','78321','561'),
('1/12/2022 2:04:02 PM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am12','78321','561'),
('1/12/2022 2:24:02 PM','Coding Complete Clicked','am12','78321','561'),
('1/12/2022 1:55:02 PM','Start Work Clicked','am78','5561','78'),
('1/12/2022 2:10:02 PM',' Icon Clicked','am78','5561','78'),
('1/12/2022 2:15:02 PM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am89','5561','78'),
('1/12/2022 2:44:02 PM','Coding Complete Clicked','am89','5561','78'),
('1/22/2022 9:55:02 AM','Start Work Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/22/2022 10:25:02 AM','Home Button Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/22/2022 10:45:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/22/2022 11:10:02 AM',' Icon Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/22/2022 11:25:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/22/2022 11:40:02 AM','Coding Complete Clicked','am115','789','89'),
('1/23/2022 9:55:02 AM','Start Work Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 10:25:02 AM','Home Button Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 10:45:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 11:10:02 AM',' Icon Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 11:25:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 11:30:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/23/2022 11:40:02 AM','Coding Complete Clicked','am115','9918','890'),
('1/25/2022 10:55:02 AM','Start Work Clicked','am115','10021','981'),
('1/25/2022 11:15:02 AM','Home Button Clicked','am115','10021','981'),
('1/25/2022 11:23:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am115','10021','981'),
('1/25/2022 9:45:02 AM','Start Work Clicked','am118','9021','904'),
('1/25/2022 10:05:02 AM','Home Button Clicked','am118','9021','904'),
('1/25/2022 10:23:02 AM','VisitBill Button Clicked','am120','9021','904'),
('1/25/2022 10:43:02 AM','Icon Clicked','am120','9021','904')


Output table

create table ##output
(ctextid int,
vbillid int,
eventdate date,
comment varchar(1000),
timetakeninminutes float,
distinctnumberofcoders int)

insert into ##output values

('10021','21','44572.5562731481','coding completed','25','1'),
('78321','561','44573.5771064815','coding completed','25','2'),
('5561','78','44573.5937731481','coding completed','44','2'),
('789','89','44583.4479398148','coding completed','70','1'),
('9918','890','44584.4479398148','coding completed','65','1'),
('10021','981','44586.4687731481','coding incomplete','20','1'),
('9021','904','44586.4465509259','coding incomplete','40','2')
```

Comment: How is timetakeninminutes calculated? How do we know which events should be used in this calculation?

Comment: Hi @NickW ....Appreciate your response... I have added a picture to the question that states how the time difference in minutes between events for an encounter is calculated..The picture has the variety of ways in which an encounter can be coding completed..Basically the picture has the rules as to what the first event should and what the following event should be in calculating the time difference in minutes.. Within the set of events that take place in coding completing an encounter the first event should always be (either Start Work clicked or VisitBill Button clicked)

Comment: @ NickW: The picture has also has the following event ( what the set of 2nd events can be to measure the time difference that has to be calculated )- Also the time difference between the different set of events for an encounter should be aggregated in minutes..

Comment: What I am trying to do is to mine the task data for encounters and calculate the time difference in minutes for the time between tasks..

In the question above I have pasted the picture on how the time difference between tasks have to be calculated...The first task has to be Start Work clicked or Visitbill Button clicked and the second task or the following task has to be either Coding complete clicked or Home button clicked or Icon clicked and the time difference has to be calculated between these individual pair of tasks and the aggregate time in minutes have to be calculated..

Comment: Now the order of tasks (as provided in the picture above )have to be taken into account for calculating the time difference in minutes for an encounter.... If the first task is visitbill button clicked and the second task is also visitbillbutton clicked then the event_time of the first visitbill button clicked task needs to be ignored as it doesnt fall in the pair of the first and second pair of tasks as per the picture..
Basically the time difference between the pair of tasks as per the picture above should be aggregated in minutes..

Comment: What is the format of the eventdate column in the Output table? You wrote date, but you pass numeric, but when I convert it to date, I get different values.

Comment: @user3369545 probably easier if you summarised all this information into something concise and then updated your question. Try adding some brief examples and show how the calculations would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to build a map between which events you count time.
Then you arrange the data in the order event_time and then you just count all these occurrences.
Please try this code:

```sql
WITH map AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM VALUES('Start Work Clicked', 'Coding Complete Clicked')
              ,('Start Work Clicked', 'Home Button Clicked')
              ,('Start Work Clicked', 'Icon Clicked')
              ,('VisitBill Button Clicked', 'Coding Complete Clicked')
              ,('VisitBill Button Clicked', 'Home Button Clicked')
              ,('VisitBill Button Clicked', 'Icon Clicked') AS t(first_event_type, second_event_type)
), ip AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS eventdate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid, vbillid, eventdate, user_id ORDER BY event_time) AS rn
      FROM input
), gaps AS (
  SELECT fi.ctextid
       , fi.vbillid
       , fi.user_id 
       , fi.event_time
       , fi.eventdate
       , m.second_event_type AS comment
       , SUM(TIMEDIFF(minute, fi.event_time, si.event_time)) AS timetakeninminutes
    FROM map AS m
    JOIN ip AS fi ON TRIM(fi.event_type) = TRIM(m.first_event_type)
    JOIN ip AS si ON TRIM(si.event_type) = TRIM(m.second_event_type)
                    AND fi.ctextid = si.ctextid 
                    AND fi.vbillid = si.vbillid 
                    AND fi.user_id = si.user_id 
                    AND CAST(fi.event_time AS DATE) = CAST(si.event_time AS DATE)
                    AND fi.rn + 1 = si.rn
   GROUP BY fi.ctextid, fi.vbillid, fi.user_id, fi.eventdate, comment, fi.event_time
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       ctextid
     , vbillid
     , eventdate
     , LAST_VALUE(comment) OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid, vbillid, eventdate ORDER BY event_time) AS comment
     , SUM(timetakeninminutes) OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid, vbillid, eventdate) AS timetakeninminutes
     , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid, vbillid, eventdate) AS distinctnumberofcoders
  FROM gaps
 ORDER BY eventdate, ctextid DESC, vbillid;
```

Query result:

| CTEXTID | VBILLID | EVENTDATE | COMMENT | TIMETAKENINMINUTES | DISTINCTNUMBEROFCODERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10021 | 21 | 2022-01-11 | Coding Complete Clicked | 25 | 1 |
| 78321 | 561 | 2022-01-12 | Coding Complete Clicked | 25 | 2 |
| 5561 | 78 | 2022-01-12 | Coding Complete Clicked | 44 | 2 |
| 789 | 89 | 2022-01-22 | Coding Complete Clicked | 70 | 1 |
| 9918 | 890 | 2022-01-23 | Coding Complete Clicked | 65 | 1 |
| 10021 | 981 | 2022-01-25 | Home Button Clicked | 20 | 1 |
| 9021 | 904 | 2022-01-25 | Icon Clicked | 40 | 2 |